# How to log in and get Wunderlist access token? (Php, Curl, API)

Tags: php, api, curl, wunderlist

**Hello!**

I need to get access token in Wunderlist. I tried various examples from the documentation, but I could not solve this problem. I think I'm doing something wrong.

Maybe someone has a simple php code example for log in and getting Access Token in Wunderlist using Wunderlist API?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share little bit more information about what you've tried, to make it easier for us to help?